# Storing datasets in a temporary location for later use?

Tags: c#, dataset, code-behind

I've got a C# project, and in the code-behind I'm filling up a datagrid.  Currently, I've got a block of code that looks like this:

```
     connection2.Open();
     GridView_Reports.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";

     // Fill a dataset so we can write it to a session variable for later use
     var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
     var ds = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(ds, "MyTableName");

     // Now fill the session variable
     Session["SSRptMenu"] = ds;

     // Fill the datagrid with the dataset
     GridView_Reports.DataSource = ds;
     GridView_Reports.DataBind();
```

I realize this was "cludgy", but it more or less worked.  Until I ran into a report that could have up to 50,000 records.  The problem is, I have an Export function on the page and if the user wants to export the data then the datagrid needs to be refilled.  I don't want this.  I want a dataset that I can call over and over without having to refill the grid by rerunning the SQL behind it.

Is there a better, more efficient way to store a dataset so that it can be used later, from the same page?  This strategy works fine for smaller reports, but it's causing my report to just clock and then shut down completely.

Comment: Looking for [DataSet.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I don't want to write it to an XML file, I was to keep it in temporary memory somewhere.